React Native, infinite bidirectional scroll view
I'm trying to make a component that can infinitely scroll horizontally in both directions.
I could set it up and it is working fine on both platforms IOS/Android. Anyway in Android there is an unpleasant blink when scrolling, mostly when scrolling from left to right.
For this component, I´m using flashlist,
npx expo install @shopify/flash-list.
The infinite list component is the following:
import { type NativeSyntheticEvent, type NativeScrollEvent } from "react-native";
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { FlashList, type ListRenderItem } from "@shopify/flash-list";
import device from "@/src/resources/config/device";

type Props<T> = {
  data: T[];
  pageWidth: number;
  pageHeight: number;
  horizontal: boolean;
  onPageChange?: (pageIndex: number) => void;
  renderItem: ListRenderItem<T> | null | undefined;
};

const InfiniteList = <T,>({
  data,
  pageWidth,
  pageHeight = 0,
  horizontal,
  onPageChange,
  renderItem,
}: Props<T>) => {
  // #region members
  const pageIndex = useRef<number>(0);
  const ref = useRef<FlashList<T> | null>(null);
  const scrolledByUser = useRef(false);
  // #endregion
    
  // #region states
  const [canMomentum, setCanMomentum] = useState<boolean>(false);
  // #endregion
   
  // #region call backs
  const onMomentumScrollBegin = useCallback(() => {
    setCanMomentum(true);
  }, []);

  const onMomentumScrollEnd = useCallback(
    (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
    
        if (!canMomentum) return;

        const slideSize = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width;
        const index = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / slideSize;
        const roundIndex = Math.round(index);
        const distance = Math.abs(roundIndex - index);

        if (distance > 0) {
          setCanMomentum(false);
          return;
        }

        if (roundIndex === 0 && index === 0) {
          pageIndex.current--;
        } else if (roundIndex === 2 && index === 2) {
          pageIndex.current++;
        } else if (roundIndex === 1 && index === 1) {
          return;
        }

        onPageChange?.(pageIndex.current);

        setCanMomentum(false);
      },
    [canMomentum, onPageChange],
  );

const onScrollBeginDrag = useCallback(() => {
  scrolledByUser.current = true;
}, []);
// #endregion

// #region effects
useEffect(() => {
  ref.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: 1, animated: false });
}, [data]);
// #endregion

return (
  <FlashList
     ref={ref}
     data={data}
     bounces={false}
     initialScrollIndex={1}
     horizontal={horizontal}
     renderItem={renderItem}
     pagingEnabled={horizontal}
     estimatedItemSize={pageWidth}
     disableIntervalMomentum={true}
     disableScrollViewPanResponder={true}
     onScrollBeginDrag={onScrollBeginDrag}
     onMomentumScrollEnd={onMomentumScrollEnd}
     disableHorizontalListHeightMeasurement={true}
     onMomentumScrollBegin={onMomentumScrollBegin}
     keyExtractor={(_, index: number) => index.toString()}
     snapToInterval={device.isAndroid ? pageWidth : undefined}
     estimatedListSize={{ width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight }}
   />
 );
};

export default InfiniteList;

InfiniteList.displayName = "InfiniteList";

The usage is:
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import InfiniteList from "@/src/components/infinite-list/index.new";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { window } from "@/src/resources/layout/Layout";
import constants from "../../constants";

type Props = object;
const WIDTH = window.width;
const Weeks: React.FC<Props> = () => {

  // #region states
  const [data, setData] = useState<number[]>([1, 2, 3]); // Initialize with current date
  // #endregion

  // #region functions
  const onPageChange = useCallback((pageIndex: number) => {
    console.log(pageIndex);

    const newArray = [1, 2, 3].map((item) => item + pageIndex);

    setData(newArray);
  }, []);
  // #endregion
  return (
    <InfiniteList
      data={data}
      horizontal={true}
      pageWidth={WIDTH}
      onPageChange={onPageChange}
      pageHeight={constants.week.height}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.root}>
          <Text>{item}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default Weeks;

Weeks.displayName = "Weeks";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    width: WIDTH,
    height: constants.week.height,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

The implementation is pretty simple so in the onMomentumScrollEnd, I calculate the currentIndex so which page is visible. Then I pass this variable to the parent, so it can calculate the new array, after the list is updated I scroll without animation at position one
As I said everything works fine except this blink in Android. The blink/falsh is caused by ref.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: 1, animated: false });
Any help please?
